Quiero que el total se muestre al final de la columna de mi pedido realizado
Tengo una consulta, tengo un proyecto de sistema de POS para restaurantes, y en la parte de ordenar el pedido quisiera que me ayuden a que el total de la mesa ocupada aparezca en el recuadro rojo,  como se muestra en la imagen, o sea, solo al final de la columna total, para que no se confunda con el subtotal de la anterior columna.
Por favor si fueran tan amables de ayudarme, no entiendo cómo realizar esa parte y solo eso me falta para poder culminar mi proyecto.
Este es el codigo lo hice con vue, php y mysql:
<template>
   <section>
     <p class="title is-1 has-text-weight-bold">
        <b-icon
            icon="order-bool-ascending-variant"
            size="is-large"
            type="is-primary">
        </b-icon>
        Realizar orden 
    </p>

    <div class="columns is-multiline">
        <div class="column" 
        v-for="mesa in mesas" 
        :key="mesa.mesa.idMesa">
            
            <div class="box">
                <p class="title is-2 has-text-grey">Mesa #{{ mesa.mesa.idMesa }}
                    <span class="title is-1 has-text-weight-bold is-pulled-right" v-if="mesa.mesa.total">
                        S/.{{ mesa.mesa.total }}
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p v-if="mesa.mesa.atiende">
                    <strong>Atiende</strong>: {{ mesa.mesa.atiende }}
                </p>
                <p v-if="mesa.mesa.cliente">
                    <strong>Cliente</strong>: {{ mesa.mesa.cliente }}
                </p>
                <b-collapse 
                    class="card" 
                    animation="slide" 
                    aria-id="contentIdForA11y3"
                    v-if="mesa.mesa.estado === 'ocupada'">
                    <template #trigger="props">
                        <div
                            class="card-header"
                            role="button"
                            aria-controls="contentIdForA11y3"
                            :aria-expanded="props.open">
                            <p class="card-header-title">
                                Insumos en la orden
                            </p>
                            <a class="card-header-icon">
                                <b-icon
                                    :icon="props.open ? 'menu-down' : 'menu-up'">
                                </b-icon>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </template>

                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="content">
                            <b-table
                            :data="mesa.insumos"
                            :checked-rows.sync="checkedRows"
                            :is-row-checkable="(row) => row.estado !== 'entregado'"
                            checkable
                            :checkbox-position="checkboxPosition"
                            :checkbox-type="checkboxType">

                                <b-table-column field="codigo" label="Código" v-slot="props">
                                    {{ props.row.codigo }}
                                </b-table-column>                                    
                                
                                <b-table-column field="nombre" label="Nombre" v-slot="props">
                                    {{ props.row.nombre }}
                                </b-table-column>                                    
                                
                                <b-table-column field="caracteristicas" label="Características" v-slot="props">
                                    {{ props.row.caracteristicas }}
                                </b-table-column>  

                                <b-table-column field="cantidad" label="Cantidad" v-slot="props">
                                    {{ props.row.cantidad }} X S/.{{  props.row.precio }}
                                </b-table-column>                                        
                                <b-table-column field="subtotal" label="Subtotal" v-slot="props">
                                    S/.{{ props.row.cantidad * props.row.precio }}
                                </b-table-column>
                                <b-table-column field="total" label="Total" v-slot="props">
                                    S/.{{ mesa.mesa.total }}
                                </b-table-column>                                                                
                                <b-table-column field="estado" label="" v-slot="props">
                                    <b-icon icon="alert" type="is-danger" v-if="props.row.estado ==='pendiente'"></b-icon>
                                    <b-icon icon="check" type="is-success" v-if="props.row.estado ==='entregado'"></b-icon>
                                </b-table-column>                                                                
                            </b-table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </b-collapse>
                <br>
 

  </section>

</template>



Probaste agregar una propiedad calculada que sea la suma de los totales, y esa propiedad ponerla en el recuadro que queres???

en el contenedor exterior ya tienes el total de la mesa, obtenido con S/.{{ mesa.mesa.total }}. Es cosa de añadir un contenedor después del componente b-table con la misma cantidad de columnas pero con contenido solamente en la última. Eso, y quitar el S/.{{ mesa.mesa.total }} del contenido en las filas de insumos
